# How to change focus of a:visited in a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm brazilian so, first, sorry for any English error.

My problem is this: I want a menu that clear the previous visited links (turning them to normal again), but keeping the link the current visited link as a:visited in css.

I have found a way to make this. But the problem is it is not working!! This is the code that I have:

```
< ul id="menuTop">
    < li id="menu-link-1">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", null, null, new { id = "link-1-visited" })</li>
    < li id="menu-link-2">@Html.ActionLink("Produtos", "Products", null, null, new { id = "link-2-visited" })</li>

    < li id="menu-link-3">@Html.ActionLink("Fale Conosco", "ContactUs", null, null, new { id = "link-3-visited" })</li>

    < li id="menu-link-4">@Html.ActionLink("Quem Somos", "AboutUs", null, null, new { id = "link-4-visited" })</li>
< /ul>
```

This is my buttons, and the code to make them "visited" is that:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#link-1-visited').click(function()
        {
            $("#menu-link-1").removeAttr("menu-link-1");
            $(this).addClass('link-1-visited');
            window.alert("test 1 !!");
        });

        $('#link-2-visited').click(function()
        {
            $(this).addClass('link-1-visited');
            window.alert("test 2 !!");
        });

        $('#link-3-visited').click(function()
        {
            $(this).addClass('link-1-visited');
            window.alert("test 3 !!");
        });

        $('#link-4-visited').click(function()
        {
            $(this).addClass('link-1-visited');
            window.alert("test 4 !!");
        });
    });
```

The problem is my code in menu-link-1 is not working. I want to remove the ul and li css and add class "link-1-visited" to it.

Do you have any ideas about how can I do that?

Comment: PS: basicaly I want to change the focus of a:visited in my menu.

Comment: Why not just use a class for the current link, rather than trying to mess with the CSS3 pseudo-classes?

Comment: I thought this. But the problem is the razor that I'm trying to implement in a JavaScript block. Do you know how can I do that only using JS?

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately** there is no way to access it from **JavaScript**, you can only display it..

The browser indicates that **a link has been visited based upon a database entry only** it knows about, and then uses default colours specified in the specific browsers configuration.

If you wanted the results just for visual presentation then the fastest method would be to use CSS counter..

CSS:

```
body{
    counter-reset: visited_counter;
}

a:visited{
    counter-increment: visited_counter;
}

#results:before{
    content:counter(visited_counter);
}
```

This would add the number of visited links before the element with id 'results'.

**OR**

This **jQuery solution** works great though.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var normalColor = $('a:link').css('color');
            $('a:visited').css('color', normalColor);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Look, I do not have success with this method. But I have found I another way and put it in the edited post.